# Using htaccess or a php file to cache only static files

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, caching, cache-control

I am looking for a way to implement cache control & expire headers to my images/css/js files. I looked for tutorials & only found ways to add cache control using file extensions. The code below is the one got from [http://betterexplained.com/](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/)

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

This sets all the images of the mentioned extensions to be cached for one week. However I don't want all the images to be cached, because there are some images that are upload by the users. I only want my static images eg: logo, icons used for buttons to be cached. It would be great if someone could point out a way or a tutorial on how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or again you could just move the htaccess file in the folder that will be cached and save the user image in another :D

Answer (score 1):

You can change the FilesMatch filter to include a part of a path. I assume the user images are in another directory than your static images.

i.e.

```
<FilesMatch "^/staticdir/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your regex more restricitive by including only only know images for caching:

```
<FilesMatch "(logo|icon|favicon|header)\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: thanks anubhava. This is another solution. I guess I asked the question wrong. With Ronald Swets solution I think I will not have to worry about the file names. But then again I asked the question wrong. Sorry abt that.